# Why not expand the Lebesgue integral by summing up a series of multiple Lebesgue integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Below is a classic example of an integral expression that can be computed using the improper Riemann integral, but *not* using the Lebesgue integral:

$$\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{sin(x)}{x}$$

The problem with taking the Lebesgue integral here is that the Lebesgue integral is defined as $\int f^+ - \int f^-$, and $f^+$ and $f^-$ are both $\infty$ in this case, because the harmonic series diverges. The sum is conditionally convergent, and Lebesgue integrability requires absolute convergence.

To analyze it from a different angle, it seems the underlying issue here is that the Lebesgue integral works by taking the measure of the preimage of small intervals on the vertical axis, and measure doesn't very much depend on the *order* the points in a set appear in (countable additivity and translation invariance mean you are allowed to break up the set and shuffle the parts around quite a bit without changing the measure!). So it stands to reason that a conditionally convergent sum isn't always good enough, because a conditionally convergent sum is by definition one where the order matters.

On the other hand, something along the lines of a Riemann integral *does* sum things in a particular order, because the rectangles it takes the area of all happen to be lined up in a particular order along the horizontal axis. So in this case, conditionally convergent sums work.

**My question is: can't we just hack the Lebesgue integral so that it does the same thing?**

The following may not be defined for Lebesgue integrals:

$$\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{sin(x)}{x}$$

But what about something like this?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_0^n \int\limits_i^{i+1} \frac{sin(x)}{x}$$

This expression seems like it would evaluate to $\pi/2$, same as the improper Riemann integral.

Obviously, going about it this way is fairly unwieldy compared to just using an improper Riemann integral or gauge integral. But does it actually work? Why couldn't something like this be used to generalize the Lebesgue integral to evaluate functions like $sin(x)/x$?

Comment: This is done and it is called a [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) even though the more common way to do it is to consider $\lim\limits_{R \to \infty} \int_0^R f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$. Splitting up the integral into a series seems quite arbitrary to me, i.e., why do you choose intervals of length $1$ and not something else? After all, this depends on what you actually want to do with it. Just to assign a value to an otherwise undefined expression doesn't make sense if you have no use for it.

Comment: An improper Riemann integral is not really an integral. It is simply the limit of a certain function, which is defined using the Riemann integral. You can define the same function using the Lebesgue integral and you will arrive at the same result in your example, because the Riemann and Lebesgue integral are compatible. But the meaning of this "integral" is highly questionable.

Comment: @jd27 Well, fine, these limits aren't quite integrals... But the gauge integral really is an integral, and it can make meaningful claims about functions like $sin(x)/x$. So, is there a procedure you can take with limits of Lebesgue integrals that will proveably always agree with the gauge integral over the same function?

Comment: @trevorKirkby I dont know enough about the gauge integral to answer that question. There seem to be a few references in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral#General) wikipedia article. I have not checked, but i would suspect that the relation to the Lebesgue integral is discussed in at least some of them. Have you checked them out?

Comment: @jd27 Yes I've checked some of that out, thanks. I think what I was really wondering about here is answered in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27775/why-do-we-restrict-the-definition-of-lebesgue-integrability?) question that I just found, so I might flag to close this question as it is addressed by that one.